# Android - create folder hardcoded get weird file without extension

Tags: android

How can I create folder hardcoded?

Have tried :

```
String log = "log";
String path = "/storage/emulated/0/.NDSCCAAC/"+log; // or"/storage/emulated/0/.NDSCCAAC/"+log+"/";
File folder = new File(path);
if (!folder.exists()){
  folder.mkdirs();
  Log.i("Folder", "dibuat");
}
```

Get result :

> storage/emulated/0/.NDSCCAAC/log (without extensions) 
>   Tested on emulator (NOX)

Answer (score 0):

For creating folder in directory pass the second parameter when creating file, have look this :

```
String log = "log";
        String path = "/storage/emulated/0/.NDSCCAAC/";
        File folder = new File(path,log);
        if (!folder.exists()){
            folder.mkdirs();
            Log.i("Folder", "dibuat");
        }
```

this will create folder log in the directory.
hope it will help you!!

Comment: still get the same result, does nox emulator not recommended for develop?

Comment: you want creating folder with above directory?right ?

Comment: sure, but i dunno why its get weird, your code should run well, so do mine